# PHP Facebook SDK - How to get specific user's photos

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I need to pull a client's Facebook profile pictures (by album name) and print their photos on their website.

```
<?php
    $result = $facebook->api('/****/albums', array('access_token' => $facebook->access_token, 'name' => $album));
?>
```

This is throwing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource. thrown in .../includes/fb/base_facebook.php on line 1028
```

We have set his albums as public, and still no dice. Is this possible, or do we have to set up a Facebook Page (we don't want to do this because he needs to upload photos via his phone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting access to a user's album you first need to get the **'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,user_photos,read_stream'** by the user. It will allow you to get access to the album pics of user.

Then, use **$facebook->api('/me/albums')** for getting all the albums then use **$facebook->api("/{$album_id}/photos")** for obtaining all the photos within a given album.

Only making the album as public don't mean that it can be accessed without permission you always need the user's permission to access his any kind of data (either public or private).

Comment: I believe the 'user_photos' permission, as well as applying the fix Sudhir mentioned (to another piece of code), did the trick.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but seems your access token has problem, try:

```
$facebook->getAccessToken(); // instead of $facebook->access_token
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this fix as well as adding a few permissions, and it worked. I think this may have been part of the issue, however NOT on the code I posted. Because of this, I can't award you the answer. Additionally, if I did, it might lead others to erroneously assume this was the fix for the particular piece of code I posted. Sorry my friend.